# SendGrid: Cannot find symbol, class com.sendgrid.Email. Broke over weekend

Tags: java, maven, sendgrid

When building my project with Maven, it is given this error. It was working Friday and somehow broke over the weekend. There has been no code changes over the weekend.

```
mvn clean
mvn compile

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project Application: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/chloe/workspace/Application/src/main/java/com/example/utils/SendGridAPI.java:[7,20] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Email
[ERROR]   location: package com.sendgrid
```

I have the following in my `pom.xml`.

```
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>com/example/Tmp.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

---

```
    <!-- SendGrid -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sendgrid</groupId>
      <artifactId>sendgrid-java</artifactId>
      <version>[4.0.1,)</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
    </dependency>
```

Apache Maven 3.5.4

Comment: No, I can't. It says I have to wait 2 days to do so.

Comment: My apologies, I am still learning the rules of this site.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently SendGrid changed their API and moved the classes around. I fixed it with

```
      <version>[4.0.1,4.4.0)</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
```